Grafana - RabbitMQ - Stream protocol connection closed socket
I am currently facing an issue connecting to our rabbitmq server by using the rabbitmq datasource in grafana.
My connection details looks like the photo attached.
I have verified that the streams plugin is installed and enabled in the rabbitmq server, also that my credentials are correct and that the amqp port is also correct and could be reached.
Still when I hit “save and test” button I get the following error in grafana
“timeout 10000 ms - waiting Code, operation: commandPeerProperties”
and while debugging the rabbitmq server I can see the following log every time I try to connect
“Stream protocol connection closed socket”
Could you share any ideas of what might be wrong in my configuration ?
Thanks in advance.
